# Authorization Problem with Django Authentication framework

Tags: django

I want to make an authentication system using the Django authentication framework. But I get 2 different errors from login and logout, which are attached below. *Django Version:   2.1.4*

When switching to account/login/:

```
TypeError at /account/login/
   login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

When switching to account/logout/:

```
ValueError at /account/logout/
   The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

---

*Some code:*
**Views.py**

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is not valid')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/log-in.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import auth_login, auth_logout, 
logout_then_login
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout_then_login/$', logout_then_login, name='logout_then_login'),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

**base.html**

```
<div id="header">
    <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="menu">
            <li {% if section == 'dashboard' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li {% if section == 'images' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="#">Images</a>
            </li>
            <li {% if section == 'people' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="#">People</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log-in</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, you have created your own `user_login` view then why are you calling auth_login for `login/` in urls.py?

Comment: It worked, thank you :) I don't know why I did it. But according to your advice, I fixed it on user_login in urls.py and after that everything worked for me.